# Ms Access: member already exists in an object module

Tags: vba, ms-access, scope, ms-access-2013, subroutine

I've looked at the other answers on here and they haven't helped me figure out what's going on. I need to clear this error from the On Current and On Load properties of the form. I get the concept behind the error - it means that somewhere in my code there is a name that is "reserved" in a sense, i.e. it is already being used for something else. But I can't find what's being shared!

Update - it looks like the After_Update sub for one of my combo boxes is also producing this error. I'll add the code for this sub if asked to.

**On Current Sub:**

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

' This will be done when Form will be opened and when record will be changed / browsed

On Error Resume Next

'load_vendor

load_vendor2

DoCmd.RefreshRecord

Totals

End Sub
```

**On Load Sub:**

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    CBQuote.RowSource = "CBQuote(NotClosed)"

    Check1354.Value = 0

Combo382.RowSource = "SELECT [CBPrimeContact].[PrimeContactID], [CBPrimeContact].[Contact Name]" & _
" FROM CBPrimeContact" & _
" ORDER BY [CBPrimeContact].[Contact Name];"


Combo320.RowSource = "SELECT [CBCompanyContact].[ContactID], [CBCompanyContact].[CompanyID], [CBCompanyContact].[Expr1]" & _
" FROM CBCompanyContact" & _
" ORDER BY [Expr1];"


customer_updates


'Combo672.RowSource = "SELECT [CBCompanyContact].[ContactID], [CBCompanyContact].[CompanyID], [CBCompanyContact].[Expr1]" & _
" FROM CBCompanyContact" & _
" ORDER BY [Expr1];"

    Me.CBQuote = Me.CBQuote.ItemData(0)

    search_record


    TabCtl952.Enabled = False

    autofit_subform1    '6-23

    update_ga

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked and made sure you have no controls with reserved names? When did the issue start - after you made a change or always? Any hints if you COMPILE ALL? You must have a subroutine with the name of one of your controls?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn When I compile the database it highlights a specific `Sub` and gives that error. Does that mean that that sub is causing the error?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Is this error specifically caused when a ***control*** and a ***subroutine*** share a name? Or can other objects that share a name cause this issue?

Comment: If you have a textbox named "Hello", then you can't have a subroutine named "Hello" (in the same module). Open your form in design view and look for the name of the offending subroutine that gave the error. Change one or the other.